# How to switch ListView to TextView to retrieve data from database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I'm looking for a way to retrieve one specific datum from the database, but right now I only can retrieve the data by using a **ListView** - not a **TextView**.
Here is my java file.

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
        searchText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.searchText);
        employeeList = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.list);
    }

    public void search(View view) {
        // || is the concatenation operation in SQLite
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, firstName, lastName, title FROM employee WHERE firstName = ?",
                        new String[]{searchText.getText().toString()});
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, 
                R.layout.employee_list_item, 
                cursor, 
                new String[] {"title"},
                new int[] {R.id.title});
        employeeList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

My XML files: main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/searchButton"
            android:text="Search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="search"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

employee_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="8px">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lastName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/firstName"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/firstName"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried to change all the specific ListView references to TextView but I got errors on the **SimpleCursorAdapter**.

Comment: You don't need the adapter anymore. Just use the returned data which are present in the cursor, after moving it to the first record.

Comment: what is mean by `How to convert ListView into TextView`? how you convert `Listview` to `Textview`

Comment: @Nilesh I was also surprised by the title. Then I read the question. The OP only needs 1 column from 1 record. So they want to `switch` from a ListView to a TextView.

Comment: @DerGolem Sorry English is not my native language. Do SimpleCursorAdapter play well with TextView?

Comment: **NO**. As I said, you need **no more** an adapter (not **any** of them). Since you don't need to use a ListView anymore. Now, you have your data in `cursor`. Simply get it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an adapter anymore. So, now, instead of this:

```
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, 
            R.layout.employee_list_item, 
            cursor, 
            new String[] {"title"},
            new int[] {R.id.title});
    employeeList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

use this

```
if (cursor != null) && (cursor.moveToFirst)
{
    txtMyTextView.setText(String,format("%s %s %s",
    cursor.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("title")),
    cursor.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("firstName")),
    cursor.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("lastName"))))
}
```

Output: `Mr. Abdul Hanan`

---

**[EDIT]**

If you prefer an output like: `Mr. Hanan, Abdul`

Then, simply change the string format and the parameters order to

```
    txtMyTextView.setText(String,format("%s %s, %s",
    cursor.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("title")),
    cursor.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("lastName")),
    cursor.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("firstName"))))
```

Comment: so the txtMyTextView is a new textview retrieved from main.xml isn't it?

Comment: It's just an example name. Use the one you (will) have in your main.xml layout. And, yes, you have to retrieve it before you can use it (typically, by using `findViewById()`)